# Need Help with a Apex Trigger for the Lead Record

Tags: apex, trigger, account, leads

When a user creates a new lead, I want to use the company name to look up a matching Account Name and auto-populate the account field.  It is safe to assume the account will exist in our org.

This is my first attempt at Apex and my code looks good to me, but does not insert.  I keep getting

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY...

Here is my trigger and my test class, can someone help me debug this?  Thank you

```java
trigger CopyCompanyOnLeads on Lead (before insert) {
    for(Lead ld: Trigger.new){
        if(ld.Account__C == null){
            if(ld.Company != null){
                List<Account> AccId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =:ld.Company LIMIT 1];
                ld.Account__c  =  AccId.get(0).Id ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@isTest
public class TestCopyCompanyOnLeads {
    @isTest
    public static void Testleads()
    {   
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.Company = 'TestCompanny';
        ld.FirstName = 'Test First';
        ld.LastName = 'Test Second';
        ld.Status = 'New';
        ld.OwnerId = '0055f000007r9X7AAI';
        ld.Industry = 'Other';
        ld.Type__c ='Prospect';
        ld.Email = 'test.test@testcompany.com';
        Database.SaveResult res = Database.insert(ld);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to make an edit, please make sure that you don't discard the formatting that other people have done for you (unless you re-apply the appropriate formatting yourself). Being disciplined with code style (indentation, spacing, naming, bracket style, etc...) is important for making your code readable (the harder you make it for people to read, the fewer people will help). The only real change I saw you make was changing the `after insert` to `before insert`. No need to do a blind copy/paste for that.

Comment: Also, don't try to paraphrase error messages. Give us the full error message (with the stack trace) _exactly as it is given to you_. When you paraphrase, you will most likely remove important context that would help more experienced eyes pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Your `...` in the error message is where literally all the useful information is. Truncating error message text is not advised. As already mentioned in the comments, include it ***verbatim***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General issues

The first thing that I see is that you have a query inside of a loop. That's a recipe for disaster. Your trigger would fail if you tried to insert more than 100 Leads at a time *at best*. In reality, that number will almost certainly be lower.

You should instead use the [Aggregate, Query, Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).

```java
// Declare variables to hold relevant data
Set<String> accountNameSet = new Set<String>();
Map<String, Id> accountNameToId = new Map<String, Id>();

// Aggregate
for(Lead ld: Trigger.new){
    accountNameSet.add(ld.Company);
}

// Query
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accountNameSet]){
    // The use of a Map here is essential
    // It's what allows you to tie the aggregate data you have (company name) to
    //   the data you want (the Account Id)
    accountNameToId.put(acct.Name, acct.Id);
}

// Update
// Since this is a "before" trigger, and you're working on records in trigger.new
//   you don't need DML
for(Lead l :trigger.new){
    if(l.Account__c == null){
        // No need to check if "Company" is blank/null
        // If it is, then map.get() will simply return null
        ld.Account__c = accountNameToId.get(l.Company);
    }
}
```

That small change alone will increase the maximum number of Leads that you could insert at once from 100 to 10,000<sup>1</sup> (again, the actual number you'd be able to insert would be lower. How much lower depends on what other triggers/workflow/process builder/flow/rollup summary fields you have).

#### Your error

As far as your error goes, you've removed enough of the error message that it's been rendered almost meaningless. I can provide little to no help with that in its current state.

About the only things I can say are:

- Hard-coding Ids in tests is, 9 times out of 10, a red flag
- Check your OWD (org-wide defaults). If your OWD isn't public read/write, then you need to pay attention to the users you're using in tests (and their profiles/roles, and sharing settings)
- Make sure you have access to the `Lead` and `Account` objects
- Double check to make sure you're using the correct fields on `Lead`

#### For future consideration

- Be sure that you only make 1 trigger per SObject (otherwise you can't predict the order in which your triggers/code will be run)
- You should keep "business logic" outside of triggers. The only thing that a trigger should do is to call into a "trigger framework"

  - The Apex class(es) in a "trigger framework" is where you should put all of the code in my "Aggregate, Query, Update" example
  - The trigger itself should only have one "statement" in it, e.g. `myframework.run(trigger.new);`

<sup>1: Technically, 20k (based on the 100 SOQL query limit). Salesforce only allows 10k dml rows per transaction though, and the only way around that is by using something like the Bulk API and chunking datasets into "batches" of no more than 10k</sup>

Comment: Thank you Derek, if you are the Derek F I worked with in 2013/14.  Triple thanks

Comment: and I will do better with the dos and donts you mention

Comment: @PatrickDowning I think the Derek F you are thinking about is probably a different person. 2013 is the first year that I started working on the Salesforce platform, and it looks like we're in separate regions of the US.